# Org mode: Insert time+date +2 hours

Tags: org-mode

I can insert a date 2-days from now with:

`C c .` and then +2 or +2d among many other possibilities.

What is the equivalent for time? What can I use instead of `+2d` for inserting a date+time in two hours (or whatever other time from now). I tried `+2h` and `+2:00`, but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

No, not quite. You can type a timestamp with a range in it like 11:30+2 to get <2015-11-10 Tue 11:30-13:30>; perhaps that could suffice.

You could edit (or rather redefine) the function `org-read-date-analyze` so that it supports "+2h" in addition to "+2d". The function is quite long, so I won't include the whole thing here, but if you look at line 16653 of lisp/org/org.el (at least in my version, might have moved up or down since) you'll see this section:

```
(deltan
 (setq futurep nil)
 (unless deltadef
   (let ((now (decode-time (current-time))))
     (setq day (nth 3 now) month (nth 4 now) year (nth 5 now))))
 (cond ((member deltaw '("d" "")) (setq day (+ day deltan)))
       ((equal deltaw "w") (setq day (+ day (* 7 deltan))))
       ((equal deltaw "m") (setq month (+ month deltan)))
       ((equal deltaw "y") (setq year (+ year deltan)))))
```

When you type something like "+2d" `deltan` gets set to the integer part and deltaw to the suffix. This clause first checks that deltan has a value. Tf it does then it first sets the variables `day`, `months`, and `year` then uses the suffix to choose which one to modify.

This function ultimately returns `(list second minute hour day month year)`, so we can just extend this clause to modifiy of the `hour` variable as well. There is, however, a wrinkle. We must also set a dynamic variable in order to signal to our caller that the user explicitly entered a time, otherwise the caller will ignore the time information and just insert a date stamp:

```
(deltan
 (setq futurep nil)
 (unless deltadef
   (let ((now (decode-time (current-time))))
     (setq hour (nth 2 now) day (nth 3 now) month (nth 4 now) year (nth 5 now))))
 (cond ((equal deltaw "h")
        (setq org-time-was-given t)
        (setq hour (+ hour deltan)))
       (member deltaw '("d" "")) (setq day (+ day deltan)))
       ((equal deltaw "w") (setq day (+ day (* 7 deltan))))
       ((equal deltaw "m") (setq month (+ month deltan)))
       ((equal deltaw "y") (setq year (+ year deltan)))))
```

I've tested this locally and it works just fine.

Comment: The manual claims that +2h will work. Documentation bug? https://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html

Comment: It certainly doesn’t match the actual implementation.